# Вопрос по спискам c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, списки, односвязный-список

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

struct Lst
{
int data;
Lst *next;
};
Lst *Add_to_List(Lst *Head, int i);
void PrintList(Lst *Head);

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    Lst *Head = NULL;
    Head = Add_to_List(Head, i);
    Head = Add_to_List(Head, (i * 2));
    Head = Add_to_List(Head, (i * 3));
    PrintList(Head);
    _getch();
}
Lst *Add_to_List(Lst *Head, int i)
{
    Lst *tmp = NULL;
    if (Head == NULL)
    {
        if ((Head = new Lst) != NULL)
        {
            tmp = Head;
            tmp->data = i;
            tmp->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error: unable to allocate mamory!" << endl;
            return NULL;
        }
        return tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        tmp = Head;
        while (tmp->next != NULL)
        {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        if ((tmp = new Lst) != NULL)
    {
        tmp->data = i;
        tmp->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error: unable to allocate mamory!" << endl;
    }
    return Head;
}
}

    void PrintList(Lst *Head)
{
    Lst *tmp;
    tmp = Head;
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {    
                cout << tmp->data << endl;
            tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}
```

Вроде бы все правильно делаю, но на вывод приходит только число 1, т.е. первый элемент списка.
Что может быть не так?

Comment: А вы тТрассировать пробовали?

Comment: @Саша Калюжный, один практический советю

Если *порядок* элементов *односвязного списка* не важен, то добавляйте новые в его *голову*, а не в хвост (как в стеке). 

Или, если не хотите, чтобы адрес головы постоянно менялся, всегда добавляйте после головы (вторым).

**При этом никакие циклы не нужны**.

Если же порядок важен, то представляйте список структурой из 2-х указателей, один на первый, а второй на последний элементы списка. 

Опять же, вставка в хвост (и в голову) списка производится без циклов.

Comment: А чем плох std::list из STL? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/

Comment: @avengerweb наверное, тем, что препод такое решение забанит - вы же не думаете, что это был кусок продакшн-кода?

Comment: @DreamChild, сейчас столько программистов, что, вообще, не поймешь что у человека на уме...

Comment: @avengerweb, естественно, это какое-то задание. 

--

А на практике -- чем плох? 

Да ни чем не плох, только вот одно -- он из [C++](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/57918).

Answer (score 3):

А вы не вставляете новый элемент в список в лучае, когда список не пуст.

```
tmp = Head;
while (tmp->next != NULL)
{
    tmp = tmp->next;
}
// тут tmp указывает на последний элемент списка
if ((tmp = new Lst) != NULL) // а здесь tmp указывает на новый элемент
{
    tmp->data = i;
    tmp->next = NULL;        // здесь новый элемент заполнен
    // а откуда список узнает о новом элементе? вам надо ещё
    // добавить новый элемент в хвост
}
else // а этот код вообще лишний: new НИКОГДА не возвращает NULL
{
    cout << "Error: unable to allocate mamory!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Т.е. проверять на то выделилась память или нет не нужно?

Comment: @Саша Калюжный: не-а. Из [документации](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new):

> The standard library implementation allocates count bytes from free store. In case of failure, the standard library implementation calls the function pointer returned by `std::get_new_handler` and repeats allocation attempts until new handler does not return or becomes a null pointer, at which time it **throws `std::bad_alloc`**.

Если память не выделилась, будет выброшено исключение.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

У вас ошибка в функции добавления **Add_to_List** вот в этом участке:

```
tmp = Head;
while (tmp->next != NULL)
{
    tmp = tmp->next;
}

if ((tmp = new Lst) != NULL) // (1)
{
    tmp->data = i;
    tmp->next = NULL;
}
```

пробежав по всему списку с помощью **while**, вы теряете связь со списком 
в строке **(1)** - если до этого ваш tmp указывал на последний элемпент списка с непустым **next**, то строчкой **tmp = new Lst** вы эту связь разрываете, а потому новый элемент добавляется "вникуда".

можете исправить это например так:

```
tmp = Head;
while (tmp->next != NULL)
{
    tmp = tmp->next;
}
if ((tmp->next = new Lst) != NULL)
{
    tmp = tmp->next;
    tmp->data = i;
    tmp->next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: СПАСИБО!

А почему такой способ не работает?
tmp = Head;
while (tmp != NULL)
{
    tmp = tmp->next;
}

if ((tmp = new Lst) != NULL)
{
    tmp->data = i;
    tmp->next = NULL;
}

Ведь теперь после первого цикла while
tmp указывает именно на нулевой элемент.

Comment: >А почему такой способ не работает?

потому что вы с удивительным упорством наступаете на те же самые грабли, снова затирая старый указатель

Comment: Да, понял, еще раз спасибо!